# @Query Insert into table using SQL query (DAO layer)

Tags: java, spring

I am using the following code in the DAO layer of my Java Spring boot project structure to insert / Post a new object (in this case Building) :

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "insert into Building (Name, Description, Id_type, Images, Address, PostalCode, City, State, Country, GpsLocation) VALUES (?1.getName, ?1.getDescription, ?1.getId_type, ?1.getImages, ?1.getAddress, ?1.getPostalCode, ?1.getCity, ?1.getState, ?1.getCountry, ?1.getGpsLocation)", nativeQuery = true)
    Long saveBuilding(Building building);
```

Looking at the query is it the correct way of passing to it the *building* parameter from the *saveBuilding* method ?

EDIT  : what about this solution is it likely to work ?

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "insert into Building (Name, Description, Id_type, Images, Address, PostalCode, City, State, Country, GpsLocation) VALUES (:#{#building.Name}, :#{#building.Description}, :#{#building.Id_type}, :#{#building.Images}, :#{#building.Address}, :#{#building.PostalCode}, :#{#building.City}, :#{#building.State}, :#{#building.Country}, :#{#building.GpsLocation})", nativeQuery = true)
    Long saveBuilding(@Param("building") Building building);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot also allows you to use the JpaRepository interface that have built-in methods to do CRUD operations and so on. You can use the JpaRepository interface and save your data from there.

If you need to use a nativeQuery, you must to use ":" instead of "?"
You can also use the EntityManager to persist your data:

```
@Transactional
public void insertWithQuery(Person person) {
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?,?)")
      .setParameter(1, person.getId())
      .setParameter(2, person.getFirstName())
      .setParameter(3, person.getLastName())
      .executeUpdate();
}
```

In your case, you need to destruct your Building object like this:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "insert into Building (Name, Description, Id_type, Images, Address, PostalCode, City, State, Country, GpsLocation) VALUES (:name, :description, :type, :images, :address, :postalCode, :city, :state, :country, :gpsLocation)", nativeQuery = true)
Long saveBuilding(String name, String description, String type, String images, String address, String postalCode, String city, String state, String country, String gpsLocation);
```

If you need more examples, see [INSERT Statement in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-insert)

Comment: I know about this method but i prefer using my method (mentioned in the question with @query). But how to use the ":" instead of "?" in the above case ?

Comment: I update the answer. See the code above, probably your parameters are not recognized by Spring JPA when using (nativeQuery = true)

Comment: I am already using saveBuilding with one parameter (Building building), and i am sure there's another method (other than ":") to achieve this. The signature of the saveBuilding method is already like this :`public Long saveBuilding(@RequestBody Building buil)`

Comment: what about the update query ? how to put parameters in updateBuilding method in case there's only few attributes that are being updated and not all of them ?

Comment: I see your point. That's why I told you to use the JPA methods, because of update. Why do you need to use a nativeQuery instead of JPA methods if you are doing a simple CRUD operation?